# Export data from matrix to txt file

Tags: c#, beginner, console, file-system

I am new at programming and I'm really confused about how should I do this, because at first I thought I should ask user which path to export. However I have been told that I should check if it exists the directory and if doesn't I should create it. How can I even create a directory path or ask user if it can be created? Sorry if my question is too odd but I'm very confused about this, I was convinced that simply asking was enough to export data.

```
static void exportData(string[,] matrix)
{

    var dir = "";
    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Insert path to export txt: ");
        dir = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir));

    var path = Path.Combine(dir, "export.txt");


    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
            {

                {
                    sw.Write($"\t{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }

    }
```

Comment: This application seems to be very simple. Could you post all of its code? You should also explain what the format of the text file is and what is the purpose of it.

Comment: @t3chb0t - what's the relevance of it being 'simple'?

Comment: Can you use json serialization?

Comment: no I can't , it has to be on console and no use of json

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ - because it's simple, there should be no impediment to including the whole program.  It can be more difficult if the program has hundreds of source files, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As I correctly understood, you want to export matrix in text file.
If its true, your code contains some mistakes:

```
for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
```

should be without decreasing length by 1 and `Console.WriteLine("\n");`
should be `sw.WriteLine();`

Also there is a not good idea to ask user to write a path. You could try to use `SaveFileDialog` instead.

Full solution

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] matrix = new int[3, 2]
        {
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4},
            {5, 6}
        };
        ExportData(matrix);
    }
    private static void ExportData(int[,] matrix)
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
            FileName = "export.txt"
        };

        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j< matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write($"\t{matrix[i, j]}\t");
                    }
                    streamWriter.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just don't forget to add reference to System.Windows.Forms